# insertText() in ckeditor component for Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, ckeditor, vue-component

I am trying to integrate [ckeditor 5](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/vuejs.html) in my vue js app.I have successfully added ckeditor but now i want to add some text at the cursor position in ckeditor on click of a button. So to achieve that i tried [insertText](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/faq.html#where-are-the-editorinserthtml-and-editorinserttext-methods-how-to-insert-some-content) method. But i am not able to get the editor instance in vue while adding the code as **editor.model.change(...)**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: editor is not defined
```

Code =>

```
<template>
  <ckeditor
    id="custom"
    ref="custom"
    name="custom"
    :editor="editor"
    :config="editorCustomConfig"
    v-model="message">
  </ckeditor>
  <a href="#" @click="addCodeInMsg">Add Text In Editor</a>
</template>
<script>
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
export default {
  name: "topbar",
  },
  data() {
    return {
       editor: ClassicEditor,
       editorConfig: {
       },
       message:''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addCodeInMsg(e){
      editor.change( writer => {
        const insertPosition = editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition();
        writer.insertText( 'CKEditor 5 rocks!', { linkHref: 'https://ckeditor.com/' }, insertPosition );
      } );
    }
  }
</script>
```

I don't know what i am missing while using the ckeditor component.Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with Vue3 and CKEditor 5. Here is what I did for anyone that stumbles across this and still needs an answer.

Reference: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/editing-engine.html#model

Setup the editor:

```
<ckeditor id="templateEditor" :editor="editor" v-model="myModel.myProperty" @ready="onReady"></ckeditor>
```

In my case, I have a list of li tags and clicking on each would add some text to the editor.

```
<li><span class="clickable emailToken" @click="appendToken('{year}')">{year}</span> - current year</li>
```

Then add this block of code to your component code (I'm using TypeScript and the ClassicEditor - you should be able to replace ClassicEditor with the name of whichever editor you're using):

```
let editor = {} as ClassicEditor;
function onReady(useEditor: ClassicEditor) {
  editor = useEditor;
}

function appendToken(token) {
  editor.model.change(writer => {
    writer.insertText(token, editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition());
  });
  editor.focus();
}
```

The ckeditor ready event passes the editor instance to the `onReady` function and stores that ready instance in `editor`. The `appendToken` function then uses that captured `editor` to make changes to the model.

Answer (score -1):

forgot about **this**:

```
methods: {
    addCodeInMsg(e){
      this.editor.change( writer => {
        const insertPosition = this.editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition();
        writer.insertText( 'CKEditor 5 rocks!', { linkHref: 'https://ckeditor.com/' }, insertPosition );
      } );
    }
  }
```

Comment: No  i already tried but this.editor is not an instance of CKEditor hence cannot get its event using it like this.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do this through the editor-object you get when the CKeditor is ready.

In the on-ready-event, you get a editor and then I save that one for using such actions.

source: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/vuejs.html#using-the-document-editor-build